# Excel VSTO : How to set a cell value without losing the undo stack?

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, cell, undo

I'm developing an Excel 2013 Add-In on Visual Studio 2013 with C# 4.0
I just made a custom ribbon with a simple button which set a value in the cell A2. 
It works fine BUT after clicking on the button, I lost all my undo actions stack and I don't know why...

I tried to set the cell value with several methods :

```
Worksheet worksheet = (Worksheet)ThisAddIn.Current.Application.ActiveSheet;
worksheet.Cells[2, "A"] = "test";

Range cell = worksheet.get_Range("A2", Type.Missing);
cell.Value = "test";

cell.Value2 = "test";

cell.set_Value(Type.Missing, "test");
```

After that, the undo arrow become disabled and I can't undo the write operation. Why ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Many actions clear the undo stack and from what I understand there is no way of preventing it. Here is [some information about macros](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-excel/undo-buffer-clears/1447c587-a124-412f-9335-c3c217afdfe8), but it applies to the VSTO development as well:

> Many macro actions clear the undo stack. Generally speaking: as soon as your macro changes any object in your workbook. There is no way to prevent that from happening unfortunately. If you want to be able to undo macro actions, you will have to write code to do so. Even then, the current undo stack is lost.

A bit [more information](http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/blog/excels_vba_undo_problem/) here as well.